# Recursively find and extract gz files without extension

Tags: linux, bash, gzip

I have a folder structure (a bad rip of an old website - you maybe know about the old double compression problem), and some files are called `somefilename.txt` but actually gz compressed. I am looking for a way to identify these files and then unpacking them into the txt files that they actually are. Environment is Linux.

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip?useskin=vector), gzip files begin with the magic number `1f 8b`, so you could check for that.

Comment: Alternatively, just try unzipping them and if gzip throws an error you know it's not a gz file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a bash function to test the file type with `file` and decompress if it is gzip-compressed. And you could call the (exported) function in `execdir` action of `find`:

```
if_gz_decompress () {
  type=$(file -bi "$1")
  if [[ "$type" =~ ^application/gzip\; ]]; then
    tmp=$(mktemp) &&
    gunzip -dc "$1" > "$tmp" &&
    mv -i "$tmp" "$1" ||
    rm -f "$tmp"
  fi
}
export -f if_gz_decompress
find . -type f -execdir bash -c 'if_gz_decompress "$1"' _ {} \;
```

Because of the `-i` option of `mv` you will have to confirm for each found file. Remove it if you are 100% sure it works as you wish (or if you have a backup).

If you have many such files and some are in the same directory we can maybe optimize a bit with:

```
if_gz_decompress () {
  for f in "$@"; do
    type=$(file -bi "$f")
    if [[ "$type" =~ ^application/gzip\; ]]; then
      tmp=$(mktemp) &&
      gunzip -dc "$f" > "$tmp" &&
      mv -i "$tmp" "$f" ||
      rm -f "$tmp"
    fi
  done
}
export -f if_gz_decompress
find . -type f -execdir bash -c 'if_gz_decompress "$@"' _ {} +
```

Comment: (a note to readers: this is using some GNUisms, but they're GNUisms that are good for security -- `-execdir` prevents an attacker trying to replace a directory with a symlink while `find` is in operation, and thereby triggering the shell function against a different filesystem location than expected; might not matter if the script is only ever run by the same user that owns the filesystem content, but if the script is run with more privileges than the files' owner it's an important safeguard).

Comment: Hm. Might want to actively delete the temporary file should `gunzip` or `mv` fail.

Comment: Good stuff, thanks a lot. `file -bi` was exactly what I was looking for. In my test with a known bad file the type is "application/x-gzip" (just in case someone tries this and wonders why it might not work ... just test with a single file) but adapting the code is easy enough :)

Comment: `find` is here to explore recursively the whole hierarchy, nothing more. The OP have a _folder structure_, not a single file.

Comment: @MarkAdler, ...if gzip files don't predominate, then you can come out ahead by starting only one child process for each (`file`) instead of four (`file`+`mktemp`+`gunzip`+`rm`) for the things that aren't.

Comment: (Whoops. Meant `file`.) I would not bother with `file`, and simply test to see if `gunzip` succeeds. The first thing `gunzip` does anyway is to look for the signature, so it will stop immediately if the signature is not there. `file` might say it's gzip but it's not, in which case `gunzip` will fail, which you need to deal with anyway.

Comment: @MarkAdler I see your point but on a performance point of view it is difficult to say which option is the best without knowing the number F (G) of files (gziped files) and doing some profiling. If we (wrongly) assume a constant overhead for these 3 commands, that's F+2G with `file` versus 2F without. Difficult to conclude.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy There would be no `file`, you only need to do `mktemp` once to get a name that will be reused, and you do either a `mv` or a `rm` regardless. You would be trading a `file` every time for a `mv` or a `rm` every time, and accessing the target file only once. Yes, `gzip` is now run every time and writing to a file every time that might get tossed. It is worth testing to see what wins.

Comment: @MarkAdler, mktemp _actually creates_ a file (using the `O_EXCL` flag to ensure that an attacker hasn't successfully frontrun the RNG, and setting permissions that don't allow others to read or write to it even if the umask would permit otherwise). If you don't use it every time you open yourself up to the symlink attacks that O_EXCL otherwise avoids, if operating in a directory others can write to.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy And what about creating the temp file once and using `cp`  instead of `mv`? Do you think it would be as secure as creating a new temp file each time we need one?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy And if you're not operating in a directory others can write to, then you can just reuse the name.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably do it like this, untested:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmp=$(mktemp) || exit 1
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"; exit' EXIT

while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    gunzip -dc "$file" > "$tmp" &&
    mv -- "$tmp" "$file" &&
    printf '%s\0' "$file"
done < <(find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0)
```

That will output a list of nul-terminated file names it unpacked. If none of your file names can contain newlines then you could change `\0` to `\n` to improve readability. You might want to change `gunzip -dc "$file" > "$tmp"` to `gunzip -dc "$file" > "$tmp" 2>/dev/null` or similar if you find `gunzip` is spitting out an error message for every file it can't unpack.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bash version 4.3 or later then all of the work of finding the files to uncompress can be done with pure Bash.  Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

# Create a temporary file that will disappear no matter how the program ends
tmpfile=$(mktemp) && exec {tmpfd}<>"$tmpfile" && rm -- "$tmpfile" || exit
tmpfile=/dev/fd/$tmpfd

shopt -s dotglob globstar nullglob

for f in **/*.txt; do
    if [[ -f $f ]] && read -r -d '' -n 2 s <"$f" && [[ $s == $'\x1f\x8b' ]]
    then
        printf 'Decompressing: %s\n' "$f" >&2
        gunzip -c <"$f" >"$tmpfile"
        cat <"$tmpfile" >"$f"
    fi
done
```

- `tmpfile=$(mktemp) && ...` is boilerplate code for setting up a temporary file that will automatically disappear no matter how the program ends (even if it is killed with `kill -9` or if the whole system crashes).  It is not generally portable, but it has been tested on Linux and Cygwin, should work on WSL, and may work on Solaris.
- `shopt -s ...` enables some Bash settings that are required by the code:

  - `dotglob` enables globs to match files and directories that begin with `.`.  `find` processes such files by default.
  - `globstar` enables the use of `**` to match paths recursively through directory trees.  This option was introduced with Bash 4.0 (released in 2009) but it is dangerous to use in versions before 4.3 (released in 2014) because it follows symlinks.
  - `nullglob` makes globs expand to nothing when nothing matches (otherwise they expand to the glob pattern itself, which is almost never useful in programs).
- `[[ $s == $'\x1f\x8b' ]]` tests if the first two bytes of the file contain the [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) for a `gzip` file.  (See [gzip - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip)).